# bash script whole file reading into a variable with newline

Tags: bash

i want to read whole file in a variable. 
for example my file is.

file name : Q.txt

```
My name is Naeem Rehmat.
I am a student of FAST university.
Now i am in 4th semester.
I am learning bash script.
I have this problem.
```

code:

```
text=$(cat Q.txt) 
echo $text
```

out put should be like this:

```
My name is Naeem Rehmat.
I am a student of FAST university.
Now i am in 4th semester.
I am learning bash script.
I have this problem.
```

Comment: Maybe check the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) before posting.

Comment: Based on comments, I don't think the linked question is a duplicate.  I believe the question here is about the fact that process substitution removes the trailing newlines, but it is not at all clear.  Note that I edited the question to add formatting to the sample input, and (I think) the question Naeem is having revolves around trailing blank lines in the input file.  Naeem, you need to clarify, as your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the problem is that your whitespace is incorrect.  Use double quotes:

```
echo "$text"
```

When you write `echo $text` without quotes, bash evaluates the string and performs what is known as "field splitting" or "word splitting" before generating the command.  To simplify the case, suppose `text` is the string `foo      bar`.  Bash splits that into two "words" and passes "foo" as the first argument to echo, and "bar" as the second.  If you use quotes, bash passes only one argument to `echo`, and that argument contains multiple spaces which echo will print.

Note that it is probably good style to also use quotes in the assignment of text (ie, `text="$(cat Q.txt)"`), although it is not necessary since field splitting does not occur in a variable assignment.

Comment: thanks for you response. but this does not display file in the same formate i want  out put should be with new line.

Comment: If you use a process substitution (eg `$()`) to read the file, trailing whitespace will be discarded from the file.  If you want to retain it, you cannot use `$()` to read the data.  But you really need to clarify if that is the problem you are having.

Comment: i want to retain white spaces.